# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720012

Tags: java, serialización

estoy realizando un ejercicio de programación.
He creado mi propia clase de ObjectOutputStream y he escrito objetos de una clase llamada Persona.
Al leerlos me salta el mensaje de error descrito en el titulo.
He estado investigando y es porqué al escribir objetos e luego leerlos, necesito hacerlo con la misma clase, tanto la lectura como la escritura. El caso es que lo he hecho con la misma clase y sigue apareciendo el error.
Os dejo aquí el código que tengo.

Arrays para escribir objetos previamente:

```
private String dnis[]= {"12345678A","98765432B","78234212Z"};
    private String nombres[]= {"Lucas González","Anacleto Jiménez","María Zapata"};
    private int edades [] = {30,28,35}
```

Aqui escribo las personas al fichero:

```
public void escribirObjetos() {
    File file = new File("personas.dat");
    ObjectOutputStream obj = null;
    try {
         obj = new MiObjectOuputStream(new FileOutputStream(file,true));
        for (int i = 0; i < dnis.length; i++) {
            String dni = dnis[i];
            String nombre = nombres[i];
            int edad = edades[i];
            Persona persona = new Persona(dni,nombre,edad);
            obj.writeObject(persona);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            obj.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Aqui posteriormente leo las personas:

```
public void leerPersonas() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Persona persona = null;
        File f = new File("personas.dat");
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream datos = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
        // Leo continuamente hasta llegar al final del fichero (se produce una excepción que capturo)
        while (true) {
            try {
                persona = (Persona) datos.readObject();
                System.out.println(persona); 
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
```

Y en cuanto ejecuto el método leerPersonas, lanzá el siguiente error:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720012
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:943)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:381)
    at Ejercicio3.Persona.leerPersonas(Persona.java:51)
    at Ejercicio3.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Mi ObjectOutput:

```
public class MiObjectOuputStream extends ObjectOutputStream{

        public MiObjectOuputStream() throws IOException, SecurityException {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        public MiObjectOuputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException{
            super(out);
        }
        protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException{
            
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: No veo que hagas un `obj.close()` o un `obj.flush()` tras terminar de mandar los datos... quizá la información no se grabó realmente en el fichero

Comment: Acabo de cerrarlo y sigue igual..

Comment: Acabo de editar

Comment: ¿Qué es `MiObjectOuputStream`?

Comment: Es una clase propia de objectouput para evitar que se dupliquen cabeceras

Comment: Sospecho que el error está en esa clase: la excepción dice que la cabecera del flujo de datos es inválida

Comment: edito y pongo la clase

Comment: ¿Por qué ese método vacío?, la falta de cabecera es lo que está produciendo el problema

Comment: es para tener varios constructores, pero no entiendo porqué produce el error, he eliminado ese constructor y aún así lanza el error

Comment: me refiero al método writeStreamHeader: o quitas ese método o creas tu MiInputStreamHeader para que no falle al no encontrar un header

Comment: He quitado el método y sigue igual